# Is it possible to run VMware ESXi within another virtual machine?

Tags: esxi

[image]

I'm trying to run my VMware ESXi within a VMware virtual machine. It fails to boot with the following message -

```
Could not load multiboot modules: Admission check failed for memory resource
```

- What does error mean?
- Is it possible to boot ESXi within a VM?
- Am not setting up the VM correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You need more memory for your virtual machine guest os, ESXi requires at least 2GB memory.

See [**Requirements:**](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere-hypervisor/requirements.html)

```
CPU
    Minimum: Single socket, dual core
    Ideal: Dual-socket, 4 or more cores per CPU

Memory
    Minimum: 2GB
    Ideal: 8+GB

Network
    Minimum: one NIC, plus one for Management interface
    Ideal: One for Management Interface plus multiple NICs for VMs

Local Storage (SATA/SAS)
    Minimum: one 80GB drive
    Ideal:2 mirrored drives, plus 4 RAID5 drives for VMs

Shared Storage
    NFS, iSCSI, Fibre Channel for VM storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it definitely can.

I do it all the time for training purposes.

The processor needs to have at least VT-X and VT-D. A I7-3770 is great - but the I7-3770K may run into issues.

Answer (score -1):

[ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html) runs only on **bare metal**. It is not possible to boot it in a VM.

Comment: How does it know it's running within a VM? And references please..

Comment: i think ESXi can run inside a virtual machine, i've already installed ESXi using VMware Player (assigned 2GB memory to it)

Comment: Weird. They do advertise their product as `the Bare-Metal Hypervisor` on the page I linked to.

Comment: @Kshitiz Sharma For a lot of details, see http:// http://www.anandtech.com/show/2480/2 (best explanation I found, but way too much content to copy. Even when ignoring copyright issues).

Comment: @Hennes Not weird at all. Theoretically an application running in a virtualized environment shouldn't be able to tell if it's on a real machine or not, otherwise the emulation isn't correct. Bare metal hypervisor merely means that it runs without another OS, not that it'll literally only run on actual metal.